# appending data rows from multiple dataframes to a time dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to put data from multiple data sources in a dataframe that contains 5 minutes time slots (over the timeframe of an hour).

for example:

dataframe1:

| A | time |
| --- | --- |
| c | 11:07:05 |
| d | 11:05:00 |

dataframe2:

| B | time |
| --- | --- |
| e | 11:10:00 |
| f | 11:03:00 |

time dataframe:

| timeslot |
| --- |
| 11:05:00 |
| 11:10:00 |

Desired output dataframe (unsure if this is best):

| timeslot | time_A | time_B | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 11:05:00 | 11:05:00 |  | c |  |
| 11:10:00 | 11:07:05 |  | d |  |
| 11:05:00 |  | 11:03:00 |  | e |
| 11:10:00 |  | 11:10:00 |  | f |

The reason for doing all of this is to make sure that if, per timeslot, A and B were provided in those timeslots.
I've tried merging A and B and then sorting based on timeslots but I have been told that it is the wrong approach.
thankful for any advice.
(Edit: sometimes it may occur that there are multiple rows from the first dataframe that goes in one of the timeslots, or from the second dataframe. this might be important later on to count how much data is coming in from the data sources per timeslot)

Comment: Why do you want this weird output and not a clean merge with unique `timeslot`? In any case, to answer your question unambiguously we would need to know the indexes of all the input DataFrames, please provide their constructors.

Comment: im building a monitoring tool that should say if, per timeslot, A and B components were both provided or not. merging A and B before might result that the different timestamps get merged and then be unable to assign to one of the timeslots, the timeslots have to be 5 minutes ones.

Comment: @mozway the indexes for both dataframes are just numbers from 1- limit. there is no indexing based on datetime or so